# Logging server events in signalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm writing a C#-based web application using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). So far I have a 'lobby' area (where open communication is allowed), and an 'session' area (where groups of 5 people can engage in private conversation, and any server interactions are only shown to the group).

What I'd like to do is create a 'logging' object in memory - one for each session (so if there are three groups of five people, I'd have three logging objects).

The 'session' area inherits from `Hubs` (and `IDisconnect`), and has several methods (Join, Send, Disconnect, etc.). The methods pass data back to the JavaScript client, which calls client-side JS functions. I've tried using a constructor method:

```
public class Session : Hub, IDisconnect
{
    public class Logger
    {
        public List<Tuple<string, string, DateTime>> Log;

        public List<Tuple<string, string, DateTime>> AddEvent(string evt, string msg, DateTime time)
        {
            if (Log == null)
            {
                Log = new List<Tuple<string, string, DateTime>>();
            }
            Log.Add(new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>(evt, msg, time));

            return Log;
        }

    }

    public Logger eventLog = new Logger();

    public Session()
    {
        eventLog = new Logger();
        eventLog.AddEvent("LOGGER INITIALIZED", "Logging started", DateTime.Now);
    }

    public Task Join(string group)
    {
        eventLog.AddEvent("CONNECT", "User connect", DateTime.Now);
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
    }

    public Task Send(string group, string message)
    {
        eventLog.AddEvent("CHAT", "Message Sent", DateTime.Now);
        return Clients[group].addMessage(message);
    }

    public Task Interact(string group, string payload)
    {
        // deserialise the data
        // pass the data to the worker
        // broadcast the interaction to everyone in the group

        eventLog.AddEvent("INTERACTION", "User interacted", DateTime.Now);
        return Clients[group].interactionMade(payload);
    }

    public Task Disconnect()
    {
        // grab someone from the lobby?
        eventLog.AddEvent("DISCONNECT","User disconnect",DateTime.Now);
        return Clients.leave(Context.ConnectionId);
    }
}
```

But this results in the Logger being recreated every time a user interacts with the server.

Does anyone know how I'd be able to create one Logger per new session, and add elements to it? Or is there a simpler way to do this and I'm just overthinking the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hubs are created and disposed of all the time!  Never ever put data in them that you expect to last (unless it's static).

I'd recommend creating your logger object as it's own class (not extending Hub/IDisconnect).
Once you have that create a static ConcurrentDictionary on the hub which maps SignalR groups (use these to represent your sessions) to loggers.

When you have a "Join" method triggered on your hub it's easy as looking up the group that the connection was in => Sending the logging data to the groups logger.

Checkout https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR when it comes to making "rooms" and other sorts of groupings via SignalR

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that - makes perfect sense, now I look at it. I'm relatively new to C#, so it's good to learn the finer points :)

Comment: There is now a persistent connection type in SignalR to persist the data or the hub.